# How to delete folder.exe virus in window server 2008

Tags: ubuntu, anti-virus, windows-server-2008

I have plenty of folders .exe files in my computer. I have dual boot with ubunut.
Nowas i have server 2008 i can't install any free anti virus there.

Any other toolwhich can help me

or ubuntu tool which can clean the virus

Comment: Some tips over here: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware

Answer (score 0):

No sure if this is still an issue anymore as it is almost a year old but there is free antivirus for Windows servers. Check out FortiClient at http://www.fortinet.com/products/endpoint/